# WPF Binding using `ElementName` fails but specifying the ElementName in Path property works?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have this xaml in my project:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
            ... x:Name="Control">

 <Grid x:Name="DetailsGrid" > // <-- I set the data object on this in code
    <Button x:Name="IconBtn" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditing, ElementName=Control}" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ImageButton}" Click="IconBtn_Click" >
...
<Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have `IsEditing` dependency property defined in `MyControl` class.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    public partial class MyControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       ...
       public bool IsEditing { get; set; }
       ....
    }
}
```

The above code fails to enable/disable the `IconBtn` button.
But the following which Binds `IsEnabled="{Binding Control.IsEditing}"` works.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
        ... x:Name="Control">
<Grid x:Name="DetailsGrid" > // <-- I set the data object on this in code
    <Button x:Name="IconBtn" IsEnabled="{Binding Control.IsEditing}" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ImageButton}" Click="IconBtn_Click" >
...
<Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Please tell me the difference between

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditing, ElementName=Control}"
```

and

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Control.IsEditing}"
```

Im new to WPF and C#.

---

**EDIT:**
But this works in some other part of the same xaml:

```
IsReadOnly="{Binding IsEditing ElementName=Control}"
```

Comment: What does `I set the data object on this in code` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Path` in a Binding expression will search for it in the `DataContext`, not in the control properties. If you want to bind to a property of the control directly, you must specify it using `ElementName` syntax. When you write something like `{Binding Control.IsEditing}`, WPF will by default search your control's `DataContext` for a property named 'Control`, which it will obviously not find.

Another way around it is to set your `DataContext` to the control itself. This can easily be done in the constructor.

### Edit

Reading your comment, if you're doing `DataContext = this`, then your `DataContext` is already set to the control itself. You should simply use `{Binding IsEditing}` in that case, i.e. you do not need to specify `ElementName` or qualify path like `Control.IsEditing`. If you qualify your path with `Control.`, WPF will try to locate a property named `Control` in the control, which is obviously not there.

So all in all, you have 3 options:

1. Specify an `x:Name` and use `{Binding IsEditing, ElementName=XNAME_OF_YOUR_CONTROL}` syntax. This option doesn't require you to set `DataContext` in the constructor.
2. Do not specify `x:Name`, set DataContext (`DataContext = this;`) and use syntax `{Binding IsEditing}`.
3. Specify the source object, by using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}` in conjunction with `Path=IsEditing`.

Comment: But this works in some other part of the same xaml: `IsReadOnly="{Binding IsEditing ElementName=Control}"`

Comment: I do `DataContext = this;` in the constructor of `MyControl`

Comment: I have edited my Question. I set the Datacontext on intermediate element. The <Grid>.

Comment: @SIDdeveloper: Read my answer in full. I have already addressed your edit.

Comment: Setting the `DataContext` of a UserControl to `this` is generally a bad idea, because it effectively prevents that the DataContext is inherited from the parent control, e.g. in ListBoxItem, where the DataContext is automatically set to the appropriate item instance.

Comment: Besides that there is a third option to specify the source object, by using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks. Updated my answer.